# Creación de varios div en si

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bueno paso a explicar: Tengo 12 DIV, aca solo pongo uno, este tienen el boton que cambia Disponible, Mantenimiento, Ocupado, y tiene otro boton alquilar pero ese nada que ver, ese estado lo guardo en el localstorage para que no se pierda al actualizar la pagina y los div estan creado con el CSS de abajo. Yo quiero crear un boton en alguna parte de esa pagina que sea "Crear habitación" Y que cuando pulse salga abajo del ultimo DIV otro más, pero igual a los que ya tengo creado e igual con los botones ¿cómo se puede hacer eso?

HTML tengo esto:

```
<h1>Control de Habitaciones:</h1>
<div id="grid_container">

  <div style="height:100px;"> <div>1
<input id="Fmbtn" type="button" value=" Disponible " onclick="sig()" />
<a href="registrarcliente.php"> <button type="button">Alquilar</button></a>
 </div> </div>
```

En Javascript tengo dos archivos exteronos.

El primero es el del boton:

```
function sig(){

 var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ",);

for(i=0; i < array.length; i++){
     if(document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value == array[i]){
         var indice = (i + 1 == array.length) ? 0 : i + 1;
         document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = array[indice];
         localStorage.setItem("estado", array[indice]);
         break;
    }
}
}



window.onload=function()
{

    if(localStorage.getItem("estado")!=null)
    {
            estado =localStorage.getItem("estado");

            document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = estado;


    }
}
```

Y este es del DIV:

```
function renderGrid(){
    var blocks = document.getElementById("grid_container").children;
    var pad = 10, cols = 3, newleft, newtop;
    for(var i = 1; i < blocks.length; i++){
        if (i % cols == 0) {
            newtop = (blocks[i-cols].offsetTop + blocks[i-cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
            blocks[i].style.top = newtop+"px";
        } else {
            if(blocks[i-cols]){
                newtop = (blocks[i-cols].offsetTop + blocks[i-cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
                blocks[i].style.top = newtop+"px";
            }
            newleft = (blocks[i-1].offsetLeft + blocks[i-1].offsetWidth) + pad;
            blocks[i].style.left = newleft+"px";
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderGrid, false);
window.addEventListener("resize", renderGrid, false);
```

Y por ultimo el CSS de los DIV:

```
div#grid_container{
    width:900px;
    margin:0px auto;
    height:860px;
    border:#999 1px dashed;
}
div#grid_container > div{
    position:absolute;
    width: 291px;
    border: blue 1px solid;
}
div#grid_container > div:nth-child(2n+0) {
    background: blue;
}
div#grid_container > div:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: blue;
}
div#grid_container > div > div{ padding: 20px; font-size: 27px; color:#D9A800; }
```

Nuevo ejemplo:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function sig(){
        var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ",);
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          if(document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value == array[i]) {
            var indice = (i + 1 == array.length) ? 0 : i + 1;
            document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = array[indice];
            localStorage.setItem("estado", array[indice]);
            break;
           }
        }
       }
       window.onload=function()
      {

      if(localStorage.getItem("estado") != null) {
        estado =localStorage.getItem("estado");
        document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = estado;
      }
    }


    var i = 0;

    function sig() {

      var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ");
      if (i + 1 < array.length) {
        i++;
        crearDivs(array[i], array);
      } else {
        i = 0;
        crearDivs(array[i], array);
      }
    }

    function crearDivs(nameDiv, array) {
      let divNuevo = document.createElement('div');
      divNuevo.classList.add('divs');
      divNuevo.innerHTML = nameDiv;

      document.getElementById('container').appendChild(divNuevo);
      document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = array[i];
    }

    </script>


    <style>
    .divs {
      float: left;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      background: red;
      margin-left: 20px;
      color: blue;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
      <div class="span2">
        <div class="well well-small">
          <h4>Habitación 1
          </h4>
          <input id="Fmbtn" type="button" value=" Disponible " onclick="sig()" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: y que has intentado?  agrega tu codigo

Comment: solo entendi que quieres crear un boton nuevo llamado 'crear habitacion' despues me perdi :(

Comment: Si, un nuevo boton, pero que al presionarlo me cree otro div mas igual al lo que yo he puesto manualmente. Aca esta una imagen como estan los DIV http://prntscr.com/kbi5vy que si apreto el boton salga uno de eso pero abajo y salga 13

Comment: ok, entonces quieres programar un nuevo botón "agregar habitacion" , el cual te crea una nueva habitación para ser alquilar.. haz intentado algo?

Comment: Si, que me salga otro cuadro de habitacion con los dos botones, de eso no, he estado viendo videos, pero ni pie ni cabeza

Comment: Puse un nuevo ejemplo en ultimo, es uno que hice algo similar, y me ayudaron acá tambien si quieren lo prueban es algo asi mas o menos, pero no salen los div como quiero con los botones y eso

Answer (score 0):

No entendí bien tu pregunta 
pero si lo que te refieres es crear una galería de habitaciones con div  aquí esta un pequeño ejemplo espero te sirva

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
  div.cuarto {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
      width: 180px;
  }
  div.cuarto:hover {
      border: 1px solid #777;
  }
  div.cuarto img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
  }
  div.nota {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="cuarto">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://images.homify.com/images/a_0,c_fill,f_auto,h_316,q_auto,w_316/v1461695219/p/photo/image/1478432/PepeSanchez_Panorama1/fotos-de-cuartos-de-estilo-moderno-de-javc-arquitectos-s-c.jpg">
    <img src="https://images.homify.com/images/a_0,c_fill,f_auto,h_316,q_auto,w_316/v1461695219/p/photo/image/1478432/PepeSanchez_Panorama1/fotos-de-cuartos-de-estilo-moderno-de-javc-arquitectos-s-c.jpg" alt="5Terre" width="600" height="400">    
  </a>
  <div class="nota">Pones una descripcion de la habitación</div>
</div>

<div class="cuarto">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://images.homify.com/images/a_0,c_fill,f_auto,h_632,q_auto,w_632/v1495161752/p/photo/image/2019168/DSC07744b/fotos-de-cuartos-de-estilo-minimalista-en-blanco-de-rra-arquitectura.jpg">
    <img src="https://images.homify.com/images/a_0,c_fill,f_auto,h_632,q_auto,w_632/v1495161752/p/photo/image/2019168/DSC07744b/fotos-de-cuartos-de-estilo-minimalista-en-blanco-de-rra-arquitectura.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="nota">Pones una descripcion de la habitación</div>
</div>

<div class="cuarto">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://images.homify.com/images/a_0,c_fill,f_auto,h_632,q_auto,w_632/v1475510602/p/photo/image/1664079/C3_View09_opcion_1/fotos-de-cuartos-de-estilo-moderno-de-nogarq-c-a.jpg">
    <img src="https://images.homify.com/images/a_0,c_fill,f_auto,h_632,q_auto,w_632/v1475510602/p/photo/image/1664079/C3_View09_opcion_1/fotos-de-cuartos-de-estilo-moderno-de-nogarq-c-a.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="nota">Pones una descripcion de la habitación</div>
</div>

<div class="cuarto">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://images.homify.com/images/a_0,c_fill,f_auto,h_632,q_auto,w_632/v1477323276/p/photo/image/1682607/5/fotos-de-cuartos-de-estilo-moderno-en-blanco-de-formica-venezuela.jpg">
    <img src="https://images.homify.com/images/a_0,c_fill,f_auto,h_632,q_auto,w_632/v1477323276/p/photo/image/1682607/5/fotos-de-cuartos-de-estilo-moderno-en-blanco-de-formica-venezuela.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="nota">Pones una descripcion de la habitación</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no debiéramos responder si no están claros los requerimientos, aparte del html y css, se debe capturar el evento de la ultima habitación para que al ejecutar la nueva sala esta sea progresiva.

Comment: Tienes razón, la pregunta era otra al principio y modifico la pregunta y ahora resine la comprendí en su totalidad. Saludos

Comment: Bueno, algo asi como lo que acabas de poner nando es lo que tengo pero diferente, pero quiero el boton "crear" que al dar clic salgan otros mas de esos uno por uno cada vez que le doy clic, no se si me entienden. Con el ejemplo que puso nando, como se pondria otro boton mas que salieran mas div iguales a los que estan?